# Different arrangements of elements in a table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a table of size $n \times 2n$, one has to distribute $2n$ identical symbols of a certain type. I am asked to find how many different tables are there so that there is exactly a symbol in each column and exactly two symbols in each row. My reasoning is that for each row, one has to choose $2$ columns between $2n$ possible rows, and therefore there are ${2n \choose 2}$ options for each row. Since there are $n$ rows, the final result would be ${2n \choose 2}^n$ possibilities. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that there are $n$ rows of length $2n$

Your answer is not correct because you have not followed the second constraint of only one symbol in each column.

To observe both constraints, you should have

$\dbinom{2n}2\dbinom{2n-2}{2}.....\dbinom{2}{2}$

$= \Large\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

(If I'm understanding the problem, which I may not be,) You are not correct.

Your approach of ${ 2n \choose 2 } ^n$ could allow for us always choosing columns 1 and 2 for each row. This would violate the "exactly a symbol in each column" condition.

Comment: You are right, I've just seen that if I choose two positions for two symbols, now there are two symbols less to put in the table.